# Find the author who added the file for commit?

Tags: git

I have made a commit that had some files which were added for commit previously. Now, I made the commit, but I'd like to find who added the file for commit. Is this possible in git?

EDIT: I was working in a remote machine through ssh. So, many folks have access to this machine.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No, sorry. Git doesn't help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Well, that's what all the answer here suggest and maybe you should mark one as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git does not record, who added changes to the staged area. It does only record, who committed the file, and when a patch was applied, who created the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes: it was you. Things are staged for commit with `add` locally on your machine, so it must have been you who typed `git add`; or it must be a special case which is automatically staged for commit after an action you took (e.g. when you delete a file); or your IDE auto adds things upon creation.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I added an edit to the question. I was working in a remote machine.

Comment: Whoever typed the `git add` part on the remote machine must have been using the user account you used, so there is no way to know who exactly typed the command. Moreover, Git does not keep track of this, because its workflow is different: each developer clones the repository, works locally, commits and push changes to the central repo. Since stage/unstage is local to the machine (no matter if you access it via ssh), the information you request is meaningless to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
git log path/to/file.txt
```

also you could use [gitk](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitk.html)

Comment: The OP wants to know who added (staged) the file for commit, not the person who committed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the commits were made, and what accounts people ssh into.

If there is one central repository on which multiple folks ssh into and then work, You can tell the original committer only if the commit was made with `--author` flag set. Something like `git commit --author="user <user@email.com>" -m "message"`. Otherwise, git defaults to using the global user and email for author from `~/.gitconfig` or local user and email for author from `$REPO_ROOT/.git/config` if it exists.

If each person has his own account on the server with each account having separate repositories, then its straighforward - the commit will be against that person's name as specified in his `~/.gitconfig`